# Let x, y be positive reals such that $1 \over x$ + $1 \over y$ $\le 1$...

Tags: inequality, triangles, quadratics, geometric-inequalities

> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive reals such that $1 \over x$ + $1 \over y$ $\le 1$ and let $a, b ,c$ be the lengths of the sides of a triangle. Show that $a^2x+b^2y\gt c^2.$

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I imagine that given the sides of the triangle the side inequality might be useful, and it`s easy to see that $x,y\gt 1$, but I have not been able to proceed from there. Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: That's not homogeneous in $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrong. Try $a=b=c=0.001$ and $x=y=2$.

By the way, the following statement is true.

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive numbers such that $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\leq1$

and let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be sides-lengths of a triangle.  Prove that:
$$a^2x+b^2y>c^2.$$
Indeed, since $1\leq\frac{xy}{x+y}$, it's enough to prove that
$$a^2x+b^2y>\frac{c^2xy}{x+y}$$ or
$$a^2x^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy+b^2y^2>0,$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0,$$ which is
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)>0,$$ which says that we need to prove that the area of the triangle is positive,

which is true of course.

Done!

Comment: I don't understand your final conclusion (with the $\sum$). See my answer for what is, I believe, a correct conclusion based on yours.

Comment: @marty cohen $\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)>0$ The area of triangle is $\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}$. I am always ready to explain. Ask you question and you'll get the answer, if I'll can answer.

Comment: I got lost when you went from $a^2x^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy+b^2y^2>0$ to $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0$

Comment: @problembuster It's a quadratic inequality $a^2t^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)t+b^2>0$, which must hold for all $t$. It happens, when $\Delta<0$ or $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0$.

Comment: Can you please do the math showing how to go from one to the other? I am really lost here :(, sorry.

Comment: @problembuster $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2<0$ it's $a^4+b^4+c^4+2a^2b^2-2a^2c^2-2b^2c^2-4a^2b^2<0$ or $2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4>0$, which says that we need to prove that  the area of the triangle is positive. But if it's new for you, we can make the following. $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2=(a^2+b^2-c^2-2ab)(a^2+b^2-c^2+2ab)=((a-b)^2-c^2)((a+b)^2-c^2)=(a-b-c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)(a+b+c)<0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant that I am still lost in the step between the two inequalities I mentioned in my first comment. It is still nice to know the last step.

Comment: @problembuster If we wish that $ax^2+bx+c>0$ fro all real $x$ then we need $b^2-4ac<0$ and $a>0$. You agree with me?

Comment: Factor $4 a^2 b^2-\left(a^2+b^2-c^2\right)^2=(b+c-a) (a+b-c) (a+c-b) (a+b+c)$ the last term is the perimeter. The other factors are positive because in any triangle the sum of the  two sides is greater that the third one

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ohhh, wait, I got it. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @problembuster You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand
the final conclusion in
Michael Rozenberg's answer.

Here is my modification.

From
$(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2
\lt 0
$
we get
$(a^2+b^2-c^2-2ab)(a^2+b^2-c^2+2ab)
\lt 0
$
or
$((a-b)^2-c^2)((a+b)^2-c^2)
\lt 0
$
or
$(a-b)^2
\lt c^2
$
(since
$a+b \gt c$).

If $a \le b$,
this is
$a-b < c$
or
$a < b+c$
which is true.

Similarly,
if $a > b$
this is
$b-a < c$
or
$b < a+c$
which is also true.

Comment: I think, your post is not necessary, because we see that you just understand all.

Comment: My proof only used the triangle inequality. Heron's formula is a lot more complicated.

Comment: I think all these are the same.